# How do I keep a user logged into a firebase app after refresh?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, firebase

I have an application built in firebase and angular, and am wanting to be able to keep users logged in after refreshing the page. Right now I have a login screen with two basic input fields which bind to a controller

```
    this.email = "";
    this.pass = "";
    this.emessage = "";

    this.loginUser = function() {
        ref.authWithPassword({
            email: this.email,
            password: this.pass
        }, function(error, authData) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Login Failed!", error);
                this.emessage = error.message;
                $scope.$apply();
            } else {
                dataStorage.uid = authData.uid;
                $location.path('/projects');
                $scope.$apply(); 
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }
```

This is all fine and dandy and it works, but when the user refreshes the page they are logged back out. Is there some way to, when the controller loads, see if the user is already logged in and auto-redirect? Thanks!

Comment: Saving the access token at Session or LocalStora?

Comment: How does one do that. I apologize if that's too broad a question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The code you now have handles the case where the user logs on. To handle cases where the user has already logged, you use the`onAuthStateChanged` method:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // User is not signed in.
  }
});
```

Typically you only want to show the log on button in the else of this function.

In the newer (v9 and up) modular SDKs, that'd be:

```js
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is not signed in.
    // ...
  }
});
```

Also see the documentation on [firebase.auth.Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged) and [getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

Comment: You're welcome. I used to overlook this one until recently and get into all kinds of problems trying to hide my login button, so appreciate the chance to get the word out about how trivial this is *once you know how*.

Comment: It looks like the `onAuth` has been deprecated. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm using `onAuthStateChanged` and it doesn't work so well as when I refresh, my app shows "logged out state" like a login button etc before the app kicks in and then shows the correct stuff. should I store stuff locally or cookies or something to make this process seem smoother?

Comment: Storing a local (preferably synchronous) value is the only way I know to make this faster. Just keep in mind that your local "they are logged in" value *may* be wrong, and ensure you in that case send them back to the sign-in screen.

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in a comment, the accepted answer no longer works. The current way of checking if a user is logged in is

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  }
});
```

(from https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged)

Answer (score 4):

I have the challenge that my web app has public pages with protected features. With the following code, the user always gets loaded via Firebase SDK before anything else (if logged in). But also gets redirected to the login page, if the page requires authentication. This work fine with page reloads.

```
Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  // If route required authentication
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {

    // Load user
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

      // If user obj does not exist --> redirect to login page
      if (!user) {
        next({ name: 'login' });
      } else {
        store.commit("user/SET_USER", user);
        user.getIdToken().then(token => {
          store.commit("user/SET_TOKEN", token)
        });

        next();
      }
    });
  } else {

    // Path does not required auth - Still we check the user
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

      // If user exist (is logged in) --> store in state.
      if (user) {  
        store.commit("user/SET_USER", user);
        user.getIdToken().then(token => {
          store.commit("user/SET_TOKEN", token)
        });
        next();

      } else {
        next();
      }
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: hey, it would really help if you could provide more info about the code itself, like which file are you writing the code for, etc.

Answer (score 3):

For any ReactJS users, here's a simple Hook that I have created based on the answers provided in this thread which redirects the user to login route if the current user is not loggedIn.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function useProtectedRoute() {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (!user) {
        console.error(
          'Access to protected route denied, redirecting to login...'
        );
        history.push('/auth/login');
      }
    });
  }, [history]);
}
```

You just need to import this hook and run inside any component that you don't want to render unless the user is logged in.

**Example:**

```
import React from 'react';
import useProtectedRoute from 'hooks/useProtectedRoute';

export default function UserDetailsComponent() {
  useProtectedRoute();
  return <div>This is only visible when user is logged in</div>;
}
```

Comment: A side-note: `useHistory()` is now deprecated, use [`useNavigate()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121109/19163024) hook instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular 4 you can use [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) - Official Firebase Integration.

I have a AuthService that wraps AngularFire2. I just retrieve AuthSession in Service's constructor and use when I need it. Example:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

    private authState: any;

    constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((auth) => {
          this.authState = auth
        });
    }

    get user(): any {
        return this.authenticated ? this.authState : null;
    }
}
```

Full authentication service code [here](https://github.com/makah/angular2-firabase-auth/blob/90fd7366cf40cb1775f9709848218d3c999cbbc4/src/app/services/authentication.service.ts)
Full Angular 4 with Firebase example [here](https://github.com/makah/angular2-firabase-auth)

Answer (score 0):

Other option **sessionStorage**

see here:

[Angular Firebase auth, how to check if user is logged in to hide login link from navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53670047/angular-firebase-auth-how-to-check-if-user-is-logged-in-to-hide-login-link-from)

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { auth, db } from "../firebaseConfig/FirebaseConfig";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

  // Function to store user data in local storage
  const storeUserDataLocally = async (authUser) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(authUser));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error storing user data locally:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkStoredUser = async () => {
      try {
        const storedUser = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
        if (storedUser) {
          const parsedUser = JSON.parse(storedUser);
          setUser(parsedUser);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error checking stored user:", error);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    checkStoredUser();

    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (authUser) => {
      if (authUser) {
        await storeUserDataLocally(authUser);
      }
      setUser(authUser);
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribeUser;

    const fetchUserData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      if (user) {
        try {
          const userQuery = db.collection("users").where("uid", "==", user.uid);

          const [userSnapshot] = await Promise.all([userQuery.get()]);

          if (!userSnapshot.empty) {
            const userData = userSnapshot.docs[0].data();
            setUserData(userData);
          } else {
            console.log("No such document!");
          }

          // Add Firestore listener to user data
          const userRef = db.collection("users").doc(user.uid);

          unsubscribeUser = userRef.onSnapshot((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists) {
              const updatedUserData = doc.data();
              setUserData(updatedUserData);
            }
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching user data:", error);
        }
      } else {
        setUserData(null);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchUserData();

    // Cleanup subscriptions when component unmounts or user changes
    return () => {
      if (unsubscribeUser) {
        unsubscribeUser();
      }
    };
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, userData, isLoading }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};
```

I have performed 2 tasks here, one is user and another is userData from firebase storage. works perfectly.

Thank you